# PIG: how filter a field with special characteres

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera, diacritics

I need filter a list of accented words, because is Portuguese.

The load is working:

```
arq = LOAD '/user/cloudera/file1.5.txt' USING PigStorage(';') as 
(time:chararray,
cd_rastreio:chararray, 
hora:chararray, 
detalhe:chararray, 
local:chararray, 
destino:chararray);
```

I need make a filter like this:

```
[...]
detalhe IN (
'A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Carteiro não atendido',
'A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Cliente desconhecido no local',
'A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Cliente mudou-se')
```

But it returns no lines, I believe is because of "ã".

What Could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to use the filter you described above (in Pig version 0.16), for example:

```
B = FILTER arq BY detalhe IN (
    'A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Carteiro não atendido',
    'A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Cliente desconhecido no local',
    'A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Cliente mudou-se');
dump

(A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Carteiro não atendido)
(A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Cliente desconhecido no local)
(A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Cliente mudou-se)
```

Can you inspect your file in HDFS to make sure it still has the character `ã` and hasn't been scrubbed by a previous process?

Regardless, you can write a regex expression and use `MATCHES` to filter without using the `ã` character, for example, with `.` in place of `ã`:

```
B = FILTER arq BY detalhe MATCHES 
    'A entrega n.o pode ser efetuada - (Carteiro n.o atendido|Cliente desconhecido no local|Cliente mudou-se)';
dump

(A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Carteiro não atendido)
(A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Cliente desconhecido no local)
(A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Cliente mudou-se)
```